# Regular Expression for a number with does not have zero in specific positions

Tags: regex

Below is the format in which the number should be:

```
123456789
$XXXX$$$X
```

The number must be 9 characters in length. None of the `$` positions can be a zero.

Can some one help?

Comment: How do you want to handle contiguous matches like this `123456789123456789`? Do you want them to return 2 matches or ignore it?

Comment: Thanks everyone. All three answers works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
[1-9]\d{4}[1-9]{3}\d
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?3231o

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat ugly but should work:

```
[1-9][0-9]{4}[1-9]{3}[0-9]
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple regex would be as below which would return 2 matches for contiguous patterns like `123456789123456789`

```
([1-9]\d{4}[1-9]{3}\d)
```

If you do not need contiguous patterns to match, then

```
(?<=^|\D)([1-9]\d{4}[1-9]{3}\d)(?=\D|$)
```

You can test the regex at [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/qIPtWLUDUY)